# What's wrong with this modified 12-pulse rectifier topology?

Tags: power-electronics, simulation, rectifier

[image]

I added two capacitors downstream in order to absorb AC component from rectifier current. Both *Subsystem* blocks are meant to form "triangular" currents in order to have these currents at both HV windings and thus a nice sinusoidal current at AC bus. At least that's the theory.

[image]

So, the idea of both capacitors, additionally to maintain a stable DC-link voltage, is to absorb AC component from this triangular-like currents. With component values like the picture I'm getting this results.

[image]

EDIT: For the record, both subsystems are just to represent why I need two capacitors at that location but scope results are from a simulation without those subsystems (as you can see, both sub-blocks are not connected to anything, those small circles indicate an open circuit. Nevertheless, the next figure shows the circuit I'll use to follow that triangular reference I told you before.

[image]

Comment: Are those large diode blocks just standard three-phase rectifiers?

Comment: @Felthry Yes, they are.

Comment: You might want to show what's in the subsystems, by the way.

Comment: I don't think that there is anything wrong with the topology. I think your expectations are incorrect. However, I don't understand the subsystems. Are they dependent current sources?

Comment: Why have you added two bidirectional switches?  What is your turns ratio?  is it sec(15)

Comment: Added subsystem explanation at the end of post. I was worried about neutral cable between both capacitors and both rectifiers and also ground path.

Comment: @JonRB by bidirectional switches you mean the last picture I added? (IGBT+Diodes+Cap). This is meant to charge and discharge fast enough the capacitor to follow a triangular reference.

Comment: I think you're a bit too optimistic to have a load of 1\$\Omega\$ with filtering capacitors of 1\$\mu\$F, no matter the switching frequency. Also, yout trafo seems to have 1nH inductances?